# Finding missing values in big data

Tags: java, data-cleaning, knime, bigdata

I have a number of tables that needs to be analysed. Currently the data is being cleansed as it has a lot of missing values. In some cases there are just one value missing and in other about 200 rows.

**Question**

How do I find what value should be inserted to the rows?

**My Approach**

1. A simple linear extrapolation  of the graph.
2. Finding the mean of the values and inserting it for all missing values.
3. In case 200 values are missing taking the average of last 100 and next 100 values.

Though I could think of all the above approaches, I am not sure about its efficiency or the method how to write the node to achieve this.

Comment: 4. Don't do any of the above. Use algorithms which can cope with missing data. Deriving values from surrounding data points does not add any information to the data.

Comment: https://www.knime.org/blog/how-to-deal-with-missing-values, i have currently using this approach. Is this the kind of algorithm you are suggesting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the new [KNIME missing value node](https://www.knime.org/nodepedia/etl-data-manipulation/transformation/node-missing-value) provides many ways for replacing missing values. It can simply replace by mean or linearly interpolate between the previous and next non-missing values.

Comment: In the missing value node i know there are many options. But when I use any method I find that all produce the same result when used for prediction. Based on what criteria can I select what kind of interpolation should be used? I get same result when using average interpolation, previous value etc.

Comment: This depends a lot on the data, the prediction task (classification or regression) and the model you are using. The KNIME naive bayes learner, for example, deals with missing values quite well without any need for preprocessing them, while the neural network learner fails when it encounters missing values. I think there is no general rule for all use cases, but taking the mean is usually a good choice.

Comment: Okay. I am using regression learner. And i have a lot of data missing. Say about 3k data missing in 5k data.

Comment: How many features do you have? Do the missing values occur in all of them? You can also train a naive bayes learner to find out which features often go together and then replace the missing values accordingly. You can also learn multiple models, each on a subset of your features and rows, so that there are no missing values for that particular model. Then you combine them in an ensemble, weighting each by its prediction accuracy on test data.